# Custom sorting with CGridCtrl with multiple columns

Tags: sorting, visual-c++, mfc, cgridctrl

I sort my `CGridCtrl` like this at the moment:

```
m_gridAssignHist.SortItems(pfnCellCompareDate, DISCUSS_COL_DATE, TRUE);
```

It uses a custom sort function:

```
int CALLBACK CChristianLifeMinistryDiscussionsDlg::pfnCellCompareDate(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    auto* pCell1 = (CGridCellBase*)lParam1;
    auto* pCell2 = (CGridCellBase*)lParam2;

    if (!pCell1 || !pCell2) return 0;

    auto lDate1 = static_cast<long>(pCell1->GetData());
    auto lDate2 = static_cast<long>(pCell2->GetData());

    if (lDate1 < lDate2)
        return -1;

    if (lDate1 > lDate2)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

In itself it has no problem. It is just that I would like to add a second layer of sorting if possible. At the moment the data is sorted on column `DISCUSS_COL_DATE`. If `lDate1` is the same as `lDate2` then I would like it to sort on the `DISCUSS_COL_NAME` column. But I can't work out how to establish the row that each cell is on in the grid.

It seems there was method called `GetCoords` in the source code (found on CodeProject) but they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: `CGridCtrl` isn't a standard MFC control. We need to know which control implementation this is. In case this is Chris Maunder's control, you could try to make it a virtual control. This would allow you to associate the entirety of the data comprising a single row with that row, which would get you access to all the data from your sorting callback.

Comment: @IInspectableIt is Chris Maunder's control.

Comment: @IInspectable I see this discussion about multi column sorting and virtual mode:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27?fid=18&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=2119956&tid=2119956. But, the amount of data I have is quite small and doesn't really warrant using virtual mode to be honest, It also means that I would have to re-write this whole section in m application. Doing this secondary sort on the names is a cosmetic nicety that I am trying to cater for. It just seems daft that a `CGridCell` can't tell you what row / column it is on the grid!

Comment: Performance is often the only consideration taken into account when promoting virtual mode. There's another aspect, that's frequently overlooked, and just as important: It enforces stricter separation of concerns, visual representation and behavior (like sorting) in this case. With virtual mode you can change either in isolation: If you decide to add a column, reorder columns, or change the display of a column, you only need to update the display code. Sorting will continue to work unchanged.

Comment: @IInspectable I came up with a solution.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just as a side comment, if this is in response to user interaction (like clicking a column header to sort), and assuming the sort is stable, then I would leave the choice to the user. They could always sort on Name first, then on Date, to achieve the same result. May be just me, but I find that such hidden sub-sort logic can be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @dxiv No, the user has no choice over sorting and you can't sort by clicking headers. This is a "by design" approach for this part of my software. This way it makes sense for the user because it is date sensitive information which needs to be ascending etc. Any other way of presenting the data would make the tool pointless for easily identifying who to select next. But thanks for your comments - in general they are valid!

Comment: Why don't you use a `CMFCListCtrl` native widget? Sorting by multiple columns is supported by design.

Comment: @sergiol This is nearly 20 year project with CGridCtrl. So why why rework it now? But I may investigate that class you refer to!

Comment: @sergiol I just looked up this class. What surprises me is that it is not actually in the Resource Editor so I knew nothign about it. I did a little play in a test app and created a Group Box (hidden) and created the control. Did not do through testing like using image list etc. It is certainly good to know.

Comment: IIRC, I used a normal list control in the resources, but I DDX'ed it with a `CMFCListCtrl` member variable in my dialog class. I think I discovered it in a `Samples` folder which came in in the Visual Studio / Microsoft Visual C++ package.

Comment: @sergiol I think there are some features CGridCtrl has that this class doesn’t. But it looks good!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: what is CGridCtrl?

Comment: @sergiol Look here (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27) although I also added other customizations (like cell merge) from other CodeProject  articles.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Where I work, we use the [Ultimate Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page) for purposes where the List Controls are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution. It occurred to me that I was adding item data like this:

```
m_gridAssignHist.SetItemData(iRow, DISCUSS_COL_DATE, CInPlaceDT::GetLongDate(kv.second.datMeeting));
```

I was being daft! I simply changed it to:

```
m_gridAssignHist.SetItemData(iRow, DISCUSS_COL_DATE, (LPARAM)&kv.second);
```

Now the item data is a pointer to the item in the underlying list.

I was able to adapt the sorting comparison function as follows:

```
int CALLBACK CChristianLifeMinistryDiscussionsDlg::pfnCellCompareDate(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    auto* pCell1 = (CGridCellBase*)lParam1;
    auto* pCell2 = (CGridCellBase*)lParam2;

    if (!pCell1 || !pCell2) return 0;

    auto* pData1 = (CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM*)pCell1->GetData();
    auto* pData2 = (CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM*)pCell2->GetData();

    if (!pData1 || !pData2) return 0;

    if (pData1->datMeeting < pData2->datMeeting)
        return -1;

    if (pData1->datMeeting > pData2->datMeeting)
        return 1;

    return pData1->strName.CollateNoCase(pData2->strName);
}
```

Works as expected:

[image: Multiple sorting]